# converting an ordered dictionary into normal dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an ordered dictionary which consist of an ordered dictionaries as value like:

```
OrderedDict([(u'catalog', OrderedDict([(u'book', [OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk101'), (u'author', OrderedDict([(u'@a_id', u'a101'), (u'first', u'Gambardella'), (u'last', u'Matthew'), (u'email', u'matthew@standford.org')])), (u'title', u"XML Developer's Guide"), (u'genre', u'Computer'), (u'price', u'44.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-10-01'), (u'description', u'An in-depth look at creating applications \n      with XML.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk102'), (u'author', u'Ralls, Kim'), (u'title', u'Midnight Rain'), (u'genre', u'Fantasy'), (u'price', u'5.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-12-16'), (u'description', u'A former architect battles corporate zombies, \n      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen \n      of the world.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk103'), (u'author', u'Corets, Eva'), (u'title', u'Maeve Ascendant'), (u'genre', u'Fantasy'), (u'price', u'5.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-11-17'), (u'description', u'After the collapse of a nanotechnology \n      society in England, the young survivors lay the \n      foundation for a new society.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk104'), (u'author', u'Corets, Eva'), (u'title', u"Oberon's Legacy"), (u'genre', u'Fantasy'), (u'price', u'5.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2001-03-10'), (u'description', u'In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious \n      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life \n      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve \n      Ascendant.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk105'), (u'author', u'Corets, Eva'), (u'title', u'The Sundered Grail'), (u'genre', u'Fantasy'), (u'price', u'5.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2001-09-10'), (u'description', u"The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, \n      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to \n      Oberon's Legacy.")]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk106'), (u'author', u'Randall, Cynthia'), (u'title', u'Lover Birds'), (u'genre', u'Romance'), (u'price', u'4.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-09-02'), (u'description', u'When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology \n      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk107'), (u'author', u'Thurman, Paula'), (u'title', u'Splish Splash'), (u'genre', u'Romance'), (u'price', u'4.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-11-02'), (u'description', u'A deep sea diver finds true love twenty \n      thousand leagues beneath the sea.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk108'), (u'author', u'Knorr, Stefan'), (u'title', u'Creepy Crawlies'), (u'genre', u'Horror'), (u'price', u'4.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-12-06'), (u'description', u'An anthology of horror stories about roaches,\n      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk109'), (u'author', u'Kress, Peter'), (u'title', u'Paradox Lost'), (u'genre', u'Science Fiction'), (u'price', u'6.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-11-02'), (u'description', u'After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg\n      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems \n      of being quantum.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk110'), (u'author', u"O'Brien, Tim"), (u'title', u'Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible'), (u'genre', u'Computer'), (u'price', u'36.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-12-09'), (u'description', u"Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in \n      detail in this deep programmer's reference.")]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk111'), (u'author', u"O'Brien, Tim"), (u'title', u'MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide'), (u'genre', u'Computer'), (u'price', u'36.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2000-12-01'), (u'description', u'The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in \n      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, \n      SAX and more.')]), OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'bk112'), (u'author', OrderedDict([(u'@a_id', u'a007'), (u'first', u'Galos'), (u'last', u'Mike'), (u'email', u'mike@gmail.com')])), (u'title', u'Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide'), (u'genre', u'Computer'), (u'price', u'49.95'), (u'publish_date', u'2001-04-16'), (u'description', u'Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,\n      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are \n      integrated into a comprehensive development \n      environment.')])])]))])
```

I want to iterate over this dictionary and want to convert it into ordinary dictionary.

How this is possible...

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do that? An OrderedDict will work like a normal dictionary as well, its just that its keys are Ordered.

Comment: Are you looking to "flatten" the nested structure that you have?  Or just convert every instance of an `OrderedDict` to a `dict`?

Comment: I am looking for converting the each instance iteratively with the given structure..

Comment: You can call `dict` to cast something to a dictionary. Combine that with a conditional `isinstance(x, OrderedDict)` check and recursion and then you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by mu in the comments, it's not really clear *why* you want to do this.  `OrderedDict`s act just like dictionaries, with very few exceptions.

But for your specific input, you could accomplish this with something like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d1 = OrderedDict(<snip>)

def convert(e):
    if isinstance(e, (dict, OrderedDict)):
        return {k:convert(v) for k,v in e.iteritems()}
    if isinstance(e, list):
        return [convert(v) for v in e]
    return e

d2 = convert(d1)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(d2)
```

The "head" of the output (`pprint.pprint(d2)`) looks like:

```
{u'catalog': {u'book': [{u'@id': u'bk101',
                         u'author': {u'@a_id': u'a101',
                                     u'email': u'matthew@standford.org',
                                     u'first': u'Gambardella',
                                     u'last': u'Matthew'},
                         u'description': u'An in-depth look at creating applications \n      with XML.',
                         u'genre': u'Computer',
                         u'price': u'44.95',
                         u'publish_date': u'2000-10-01',
                         u'title': u"XML Developer's Guide"},
                        {u'@id': u'bk102',
                         u'author': u'Ralls, Kim',
                         u'description': u'A former architect battles corporate zombies, \n      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen \n      of the world.',
                         u'genre': u'Fantasy',
                         u'price': u'5.95',
                         u'publish_date': u'2000-12-16',
                         u'title': u'Midnight Rain'},
```

Comment: Actully, I have converted the xml file into dict using xmltodict package, the content are something like <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author a_id="a101">
  <first>Gambardella </first>
  <last> Matthew</last>
  <email> matthew@standford.org</email>
      </author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>